# CentOS 8 отсутствует messages и secure

Tags: linux, логирование, centos8

На CentOS 8 (CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core)) не обнаружил файлов messages и secure в дериктории var/log/.
Очень хотелось бы узнать почему их там нету? И как сделать так, что бы всё таки логирование было в файлах messages и secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ищите логи в журнале (journalctl). Последние годы только и делаю что отключаю запись в messages. Включить можно через

```
systemctl enable rsyslog
systemctl start rsyslog
```

И проверь настройку /etc/systemd/journald.conf  что там включёно перенаправление в сислог

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю насчёт CentOS, но поскольку он основан на RedHat, то (IMHO) в нём так же, как и в fedora, этих файлов действительно нет. А в каталоге /var/log лежит файл README, в котором написано:

> You are looking for the traditional text log files in /var/log, and
> they are gone?
>
> Here's an explanation on what's going on:
>
> You are running a systemd-based OS where traditional syslog has been
> replaced with the Journal. The journal stores the same (and more)
> information as classic syslog. To make use of the journal and access
> the collected log data simply invoke "journalctl", which will output
> the logs in the identical text-based format the syslog files in
> /var/log used to be. For further details, please refer to
> journalctl(1).

Comment: Интеренсно, у меня этого README файла нету. Есть разные другие логи, но нету messages и secure...

Comment: @Dikens Ну так Вам удалось посмотреть лог с помощью *journalctl* ?

Comment: Не очень... хотелось бы узнать через лог узнать когда, кто и через что авторизовывался или не удачные попыки авторизоваться на сервере.

Comment: @Dikens - "кто и через что авторизовывался"  - Тогда Вам нужно смотреть файл */var/log/wtmp* - там полная информация. Посмотреть последние 5 записей о пользователи Dikens можно так : *last Dikens | head -5*